# Как ввести список пар чисел в скобках и добавить их в два массива координат?

Tags: python, строки, парсер, десериализация

Нужно ввести пары чисел и добавить их в два массива координат X и Y. Ввод, например:

```
(0, 5), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 7), (4, 5), (5, 2), (6, 0), (7, 6)
```

Пока получается только убрать знаки:

```
string = input()
string = string.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(",", '')
print(string)
```

Но как добавить их попарно в массив координат?

Знаю как делать вот такой ввод в столбик:

```
1 1
2 2
4 7
6 6
2 4
3 3
4 4
7 3
```

Код:

```
n = 8
x = []
y = []
for i in range(n):
    new_x, new_y = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
    x.append(new_x)
    y.append(new_y)
```

Как сделать такое же для строки?

```
(0, 5), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 7), (4, 5), (5, 2), (6, 0), (7, 6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно распарсить регулярным выражением.

```
import re
s = "(0, 5), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 7), (4, 5), (5, 2), (6, 0), (7, 6)"
x,y = list(map(list, zip(*[list(map(int, pair)) for pair in re.findall(r"\((\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\)", s)])))
print(x)
print(y)
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[5, 1, 3, 7, 5, 2, 0, 6]
```

Ну или оно же, но в более понятном виде:

```
x,y = [],[]
for pair in re.findall(r"\((\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\)", s):
    x.append(int(pair[0]))
    y.append(int(pair[1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно привести строку к виду `"[[0, 5], [1,1], ...]"` и после этого спарсить эту строку при помощи [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

s = "(0, 5), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 7), (4, 5), (5, 2), (6, 0), (7, 6)"

points = json.loads(f"""[{s.replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]")}]""")

print(points)
# [[0, 5], [1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 7], [4, 5], [5, 2], [6, 0], [7, 6]]
```

чтобы разнести координаты по отдельным кортежам:

```
x, y = zip(*points)

print(x)
# (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

print(y)
# (5, 1, 3, 7, 5, 2, 0, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/mcQu34

```
import re

t = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+", input())]

a = t[::2]
b = t[1::2]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: ну вот опять: ни объяснения, как именно предложенный код отвечает на вопрос, ни пояснения, чем предложение, изложенное в этом ответе, отличается от прочих предложений…

Answer (score 0):

превратить заданную строку в список вы можете так:

```
pairs = eval(f'[{input()}]')
```

функция `eval()` вычисляет выражение переданное ей в виде строки, в данном случае получаем список.

а дальше вы уже знаете.

```
x, y = zip(*pairs)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте хоть предупреждение, если предлагаете решение с использованием eval (на всякий случай).

Comment: @0xdb, ок. Не думал что это настолько опасно. Сам всегда использовал не задумываясь. Что ж, учту.